# Google Tag Manager connection with Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having an issue with the settings of the tags in Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics. I created a tag in Tag Manager that uses my Analytics ID and I'm able to see the custom variables in the Tag Manager, but they're not being sent to Analytics.

I suspect the issue might be in the other settings of the tag, but I'm not sure what's causing the problem. Can someone help me understand how these other settings affect the way variables are transferred between Tag Manager and Analytics?

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions you could provide to help me solve this problem. Thank you!

I tried creating a tag in Google Tag Manager that uses my Analytics ID and includes some custom variables. I was expecting to see these variables in Google Analytics, but they are not showing up.

I also checked the Tag Manager debug mode to see if there were any errors, but everything seems to be working fine. I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provide any info about how you are managing this connection between your GTM and analytics.google. I suppose you are sending your info through datalayer.send. So, you need to create all custom dimensions in analytics.google profile and it takes 48 hours to get effected. Remember, once created a custom dimension the Event parameter related to that dimension is not modifiable.
Then, you have to go to you GTM profile and create a Configuration Tag, and you have to set the Measurement Id equal to the Measurement Id obtained from you analytics.google profile like the photo below:
Remember to select GA4 Configuration as the type.

[image]

then, you should create another tag  and consequently a trigger:

[image]

To create the custom variables which are going to be set as **User-Defined Variables**. If they are going to get their values from datalayer.send then you need to define their types as "**Data Layer Variable**" , this means that you should ask the developers to set this value while you are initializing the GA4 function.
otherwise, if you are considering this parameter as a Javascript or Custom Javascript, then you should set the info correspondingly depending on your requirements and ask the developers to provide these info for GA4.
Also GTM needs 24 hours to handle the changes.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't comment on my code implementation because I thought it was unnecessary. I believe the issue I'm facing is related to this configuration in Google's platforms, and I had already set up these datalayer variables. I had also created custom dimensions in Analytics, but I don't know how to link all these things together. I read in some Google documentation that it was necessary to create a tag with my Analytics ID, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @cyro.alves you need to create a tag configuration first, i edit my response